# Column 'RowIdent' does not belong to table

Tags: c#, .net, erp

I am trying to add a row to a DataTable using the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < datesCount; i++
{
    // Populate payments table with existing data  
    DataRow newPaymentRow = PaymentsMadeDataTable.NewRow();
    newPaymentRow["Date"] = datesSplit[i];
    newPaymentRow["Description"] = descSplit[i];    
    newPaymentRow["Amount"] = Convert.ToDecimal(amountSplit[i]);
    // Add row to data table
    PaymentsMadeDataTable.Rows.Add(newPaymentRow);
}
```

I am receiving the following Error, "Column 'RowIdent' does not belong to table".

What could be causing this error?

Comment: where is the `RowIdent` in your code?

Comment: Why do you use the `\` symbol for your []?

Comment: There is no RowIdent which is why i'm unsure of the error message appearing. Secondly, i'm using the " symbol not ``. I think its just the way the code has been formatted by stackoverflow